# WSO2 Identity Server using OpenID Connect returns an authorization code even if the user denies granting authorization

Tags: wso2, openid, oauth2-playground, wso2-identity-server

When I run the playground2 openid connect example, I can still see the photos even if I deny authorization.  I have the user login in and authenticate successfully, but deny the authorization.  From the OpenID Connect specification, an error code should be returned, but instead I am still getting the authorization code.  I am running WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.

Why is it still sending an authorization token?

Answer (score 0):

The validation of the Access Token is disabled in the playground app. You could enable it with un-commenting line 34-40 in 'oauth-access-resource.jsp.

```
  if (!client.validateAuthenticationRequest(oauthReq)) {
    %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location = "oauth2.jsp?reset=true&error='Invalid Access Attempt'";
    </script>
    <%
  }
```

Comment: I am running the playground app from the 4.6 identity server source.  It is not commented out.  The %> and <% are scriptlet tags, not comment tags.  It still doesn't does not deny access.  I did try running that code and it validated correctly.